# Using Python to set Windows ErrorLevel

Tags: python, command-line, windows-10, errorlevel

I'm investigating an application that runs programs via a YAML file.

I need to write a Python script that exits with the code specified in the command line argument[1].

My attempt (`exit_code_argument.py`):

```
import sys
sys.exit(sys.argv[1])
```

The idea is for the Python script to set the Windows Command Prompt's `ErrorLevel` variable on exit or termination of the script.

I'm always getting ErrorLevel set to zero:

```
C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>python exit_code_argument.py 1
1

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>python exit_code_argument.py 27
27

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>python exit_code_argument.py 3
3

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>python exit_code_argument.py 0
0

C:\sandboxes\git\utfa>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

My goal is to run `exit_code_argument.py 3` and have the statement `echo %errorlevel%` print 3 on the console (same number as the first parameter to `exit_code_argument.py`).

What am I doing wrong or how do I fix the Python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to return an integer, and you're returning a  string.  Try:

```
sys.exit(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

and you should achieve happiness.